# How to write Redshift stored procedure using aggregate functions?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to write a stored procedure using aggregate functions. Is there some place where I could refer for this?

I couldn't find any concrete material.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "using"?  Stored procedures often have queries in them and these queries can aggregate.  So I think you want to use aggregate functions in some other way.  Please clarify.

Comment: Stored procedures with aggregate functions

Comment: Let's try this - the stored procedure test_sp2 on this page has an aggregate function in the procedure - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html  Is this the kind of use you are looking for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.